# Dynamically created Radiobutton list not firing onselected

Tags: c#, webforms

[image]

There is a dynamically created radiolist button and the aim is to fire an even when the radio button is clicked. This is in a panel pnldynamic

```
    pnldynamic.Controls.Add(lbl);
                                RadioButtonList rd = new RadioButtonList();

                                foreach (CustomerFile cu in allCustomerFile)
                                {
                                       rd.Items.Add(cu.ApplicationNumber.ToString());

                                }
    rd.AutoPostBack = true;
           rd.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
        pnldynamic.Controls.Add(rd);
```

> Following is the eventhandler for radiobuttonlist on selectedindex
>   change

```
       private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton btn = sender as RadioButton;
            txtReferenceNumber.Text = btn.Text;
                   }
```

The breakpoint in the function is not getting hit when the  radiobuttonlist is selected

Comment: Resolved using the radiobuttonlist in aspx page and fill the data from .cs file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RadioButtonList rd = new RadioButtonList();
foreach (CustomerFile cu in allCustomerFile
{
    rd.Items.Add(cu.ApplicationNumber.ToString());
}
rd.AutoPostBack = true;
rd.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
pnldynamic.Controls.Add(rd);
```

Comment: The event is still not fired. Can panel cause a problem?